# PivotViewer control doesn't Display Images (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, deepzoom, pivotviewer

I use the excel plug-in to publish them, then i copy the cxml and the folder to my .web project and when i run the pivot works and has the categories but doesnt show images.

xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
<pivot:PivotViewer x:Name="PivotViewer" Height="310"></pivot:PivotViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

home code:

```
PivotViewer.LoadCollection("http://localhost:2287/Test2.cxml",null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@stuart @alison Thank you bothI found the solution. When you have the pivot in a container like stackpanel, you have to put the width and height. If you do not declare its height and width they are infinite and the images wont render.
This is how i solved it.

```
<StackPanel Height="437" Width="960"> 
<pivot:PivotViewer x:Name="PivotViewer" Height="310"></pivot:PivotViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That's right.  The StackPanel is dimensionless and the Height and Width constraints are required for the PivotViewer.  I guess from the XAML in your question I assumed that you had a reason for not including these requirements hence the need to take it out of the StackPanel.  Regardless, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Take the PivotViewer out of the StackPanel.  The StackPanel is known to break PivotViewer layouts.

Comment: your answer is almost correct but doesnt fit in my project, though i found the way to fix it check my answer. :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply a lot more information than that to help us debug this.

Some basic advice is:

- Check that the pathing for all your files - dzi, dzc, png, etc - is correct.
- Also, try it on different browsers - I've noticed a lot of caching going on (so if it fails first time then it might fail every later time too)

Comment: I was aware of the caching problem, thnx anyhow :) also in my solution i changed the path of the first xml but pivot wanted something more than that.